# How to run Dropwizard app in debug mode with Eclipse?

Tags: java, classpath, dropwizard, default-package

I'm looking to run my Dropwizard 0.8.5 app in **debug mode** whereby:

- The app is running locally, using JPDA; and
- In my IDE (Eclipse) I set breakpoints and use a JPDA client to connect to my locally running app (I think this is how it goes)

---

#### For the server debug mode:

Typically my DW app runs from the command-line like so:

```
java -jar build/libs/myapp.jar server src/test/resources/myapp-local.yml
```

**So what are the command-line args to get this running in debug mode (JPDA), or what are the modifications to `myapp-local.yml` needed to accomplish this?**

---

#### For Eclipse/JPDA Client

I assume I just set breakpoints and then create a new **Debug Configuration** inside Eclipse, but not sure what arguments/configs to set this Configuration up with. **Any ideas?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just run the main class (the one that extends `Application<T>`) in debug mode. You will need to set the program parameters as `"server  src/test/resources/myapp-local.yml"` in your run configurations.

Comment: Thanks @dkulkarni (+1) - **what if I want to debug a remote running DW app, say, one of our DEV or QA servers?**

Comment: First, you will need to add multiple options to your `java -jar` command to setup remote debugging. You can then attach a listener in Eclipse to debug remotely. Detailed instructions here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/enable-remote-debugging.html